# WSO2 - Aggregation SOAP and Rest Response into Rest

Tags: wso2

I am trying to do proof of concept in Wso2( new to wso2, this is my 3rd week with Wso2) using clone and aggregation using weather soap and rest api. 
The scenario is Client will initate soap request , Wso2 filter and clone request and sends weather soap and rest API GetCityWeatherByZIP operation, the response from both are collected in aggregation and sends soap response to the client.
My question is how to convert rest response(jsonObject) to soap response and add as child to other GetCityWeatherByZIP soap response and return to the client, when client receives response, soap body should have 2GetCityWeatherByZIPResult inside GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse .

any help would be much appreciated.

here is my proxy configuration

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="CloneAggregateProxy" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
            <log level="full">
                <property xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:weat="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/" name="uri.var.zip" expression="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/weat:GetCityWeatherByZIP/weat:ZIP"/>
            </log>
            <filter xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:weat="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/" xpath="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/weat:GetCityWeatherByZIP">
                <then>
                    <property name="uri.var.zip" expression="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/weat:GetCityWeatherByZIP/weat:ZIP" scope="default" type="STRING" description=""/>
                    <log level="full">
                        <property name="zipCode" expression="get-property('uri.var.zip')"/>
                    </log>
                    <clone id="edbIhub">
                        <target>
                            <endpoint>
                                <address uri="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx"/>
                            </endpoint>
                        </target>
                        <target>
                            <endpoint>
                                <http method="get" uri-template="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={uri.var.zip}"/>
                            </endpoint>
                        </target>
                    </clone>
                </then>
                <else/>
            </filter>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING" description="messageType"/>
            <log level="full" description="">
                <property name="WSANSWER" value="true"/>
            </log>
            <aggregate>
                <completeCondition timeout="60">
                    <messageCount min="2" max="2"/>
                </completeCondition>
                <onComplete xmlns:s12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" expression="/s11:Envelope/s11:Body/child::*[position()=1] | /s12:Envelope/s12:Body/child::*[position()=1]">
                    <log level="full" description="json">
                        <property name="json" expression="$body/jsonObject"/>
                    </log>

                    <property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
                </onComplete>
            </aggregate>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

Rest Response in xml(with jsonObject ).

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><jsonObject><coord><lon>-96.99</lon><lat>32.87</lat></coord><sys><message>0.0237</message><country>US</country><sunrise>1428408443</sunrise><s
352</sunset></sys><weather><id>800</id><main>Clear</main><description>Sky is Clear</description><icon>01d</icon></weather><base>stations</base><main><temp>301.125</temp><temp_min>301.125</temp_min>
<temp_max>301.125</temp_max><pressure>10e><sea_level>1027.22</sea_level><grnd_level>1003.5</grnd_level>
<humidity>69</humidity></main><wind><speed>8.07</speed><deg>200.504</deg></wind><clouds><all>0</all></clouds>
<dt>1428433031</dt><id>0</id><name>Irving</name><cod>200</cod></j
oapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

SOAP Response.

```
<?xml version="1.0"
-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soap:Body><GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.
/"><GetCityWeatherByZIPResult><Success>true</Success><ResponseText>City Found</ResponseText><State>TX</State><City>Irving</City><WeatherStationCity>Euless</WeatherStationCity>
<WeatherID>14</WeatherID><Description>Cloudy</Description><TemTemperature>
<RelativeHumidity>84</RelativeHumidity><Wind>NE7</Wind><Pressure>29.86S</Pressure><Visibility></Visibility>
<WindChill></WindChill><Remarks></Remarks></GetCityWeatherByZIPResult></GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse></soap:Body>
</soap>
```

Comment: Here is full configuration

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use payloadFactoryMediator[1].  for this. In your outSequence inside OnComplete use payload Factory mediator to construct the response you need

E.g.

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
         <m:GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse xmlns:m="http://ws.cdyne.">
              <m:GetCityWeatherByZIPResult>
                  <m:Success>true</m:Success>
                  .....
                  .....

              </m:GetCityWeatherByZIPResult>
         </m:GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse>
    </format>
    <args>
        ...
        ...
   </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/PayloadFactory+Mediator